# Генерация source map для файлов, подключаемых с помощью require

Tags: javascript, gulp

Имеем gulp-таск

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src('*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps/', {includeContent: false}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

И js-файл примерно такого содержания

```
require('foo.js');
require('bar.js');

//some local code
```

Source map в этом случае создается для сконкатенированного общего js-файла, в который попадает код из foo.js, bar.js и файла, в котором они подключаются. И строчки в сгенерированном source map указывают на номера строк в этом файле.

Нужно, чтобы маппинг был на конкретные конечные файлы foo.js и bar.js Как это можно сделать? Возможно, с использованием каких-то других плагинов.

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном вами примере проще сгенерировать *source map* средствами *browserify*. Для этого вам нужно запустить *browserify* с опцией *debug*.

Такой код должен работать:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src('*.js')
        .pipe(browserify({debug: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./')); });
```

Если вы хотите добавить дополнительные настройки в *gulp* к полученным *source map*, например сохранить их в отдельную папку, то вам должен подойти этот код:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
        gulp.src('*.js')
            .pipe(browserify({debug: true}))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps/'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./')); });
```

Код выше я не проверял, но в любом случае вам нужно будет генерировать *source map* средствами *browserify*.

Comment: Это не относится к вашему вопросу, но если вам не важно чем собирать CommonJS модули то я бы вам посоветовал [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/). Там гораздо больше возможностей, в том числе и для генерации source map.